# Abbreviate "listing" in cleveref

Tags: tcolorbox, cleveref

Is there a way to make cleveref abbreviate "listing" into "lis.", except at the beginning of a sentence?  In other words, make it behave like "equation"?

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting[auto counter,number within=chapter,crefname={listing}{listings}]{labelboxcode}[3][]{%
    listing options={language=Java,#1},
    listing and comment,
    comment={Listing~\thetcbcounter: #3},
    label=#2
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{labelboxcode}{foo}{Class \texttt{Foo}.}
class Foo {}
\end{labelboxcode}

\Cref{foo} is class \verb;Foo; (\cref{foo}).
\end{document}
```

I expected `\cref{foo}` to produce `lis. 1.1` instead of `listing 1.1`.

Comment: What's the name of the counter that's used in the cross-reference, and how is it displayed at present by `\cref`? Do you employ the `listings` package?

Comment: I'm actually using `tcolorbox`, which has a mechanism for `cleveref` labels.  They have type `listing` and are currently displayed as `listing`, with proper capitalization and plural forms.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) of your current setup.

Comment: Added example to main post.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is replace the single option

```
crefname={listing}{listings}
```

with the following pair of options:

```
crefname={lis.}{listings}
Crefname={Listing}{Listings}
```

This works because the `crefname={lis.}{listings}` option generates LaTeX code to execute `\crefname{listing}{lis.}{listings}` for use by the `cleveref` package. By default, if a `\crefname` but no corresponding `\Crefname` macro is run, `cleveref` builds the form of the label to be used by `\Cref` by uppercasing the first letters in the two arguments of `\crefname`. The default mechanism can be overridden by providing the `tcbcolorbox` option `Crefname={Listing}{Listings}`.

---

A full MWE; the `hyperref` package and cleveref's `nameinlink` option are used merely to highlight the respective outputs of `\Cref` and `\cref`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting[auto counter,
               number within=chapter,
               crefname={lis.}{listings},  % was: {listing}{listings}
               Crefname={Listing}{Listings}% <-- new
              ]
              {labelboxcode}[3][]{%
               listing options={language=Java,#1},
               listing and comment,
               comment={Listing~\thetcbcounter: #3},
               label=#2}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\begin{labelboxcode}{foo}{Class \texttt{Foo}.}
   class Foo {}
\end{labelboxcode}

\noindent
\Cref{foo} is class \verb;Foo; (\cref{foo}).

\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautifully simple! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I still have one minor problem someone might be able to help me with.  Unfortunately, the demo code is getting longer; I doubt it'll fit in a comment.  Do I need to start a new question?

Comment: @MichelCharpentier - If the MWE (minimum working example) code is getting quite long, it's probably a good idea to post a new question. (Of course, for reference, you can always post a link to an earlier query in a new query.)

Comment: Ok.  Discussion continues in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/600330/171866...