# Multiple types of labeled boxes handled as one by cleveref

Tags: tcolorbox, cleveref

This is a followup to my question [Abbreviate "listing" in cleveref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/598365/171866), as the MWE is getting longer:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,cleveref}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,listings,breakable}

% Code box, numbered, unbreakable
\newtcblisting[auto counter,
               number within=chapter,
               crefname={lis.}{lis.},
               Crefname={Listing}{Listings},
               list inside=lis
              ]{labelboxcode}[4][]{%
    title=#2,
    listing options={language=#2,#1},
    comment={Listing~\thetcbcounter: #4},
    list text={#4},
    label=#3,
    listing and comment
}

% Code box, numbered, breakable
\newtcblisting[use counter from=labelboxcode,
               crefname={lis.}{lis.},
               Crefname={Listing}{Listings},
               list inside=lis
              ]{labelboxcode*}[4][]{%
    breakable,
    title=#2,
    listing options={language=#2,#1},
    comment={Listing~\thetcbcounter: #4},
    list text={#4},
    label=#3,
    listing and comment
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Demo}

This is a Java program:

\begin{labelboxcode}{Java}{java-listing}{A Java program, contrast with \cref{scala-listing}.}
int abs(int x) {
  if (x > 0)
    return x;
  else
    return -x;
}
\end{labelboxcode}
\Cref{java-listing} can be referenced as \cref{java-listing}.

\Cref{scala-listing} is the same program in Scala:

\begin{labelboxcode}{Scala}{scala-listing}{A Scala program, contrast with \cref{java-listing}.}
def abs(x: Int) = if x > 0 then x else -x
\end{labelboxcode}

\Cref{java-listing,scala-listing} compute the same function.

This is a breakable listing:

\begin{labelboxcode}{ML}{sml-listing}{An SML program.}
fun abs x = if x > 0 then x else ~x;
\end{labelboxcode}

All three listings can be referred to in one swoop: \cref{java-listing,scala-listing,sml-listing}
\end{document}
```

The idea is to define boxes for programming languages in two variants, breakable and non-breakable. The code above uses non-breakable boxes and works fine. In particular, it produces the line `one swoop: lis. 1.1 to 1.3` at the end.
My problems start when one of the boxes is set to be breakable. The listings are still numbered correctly (i.e., within the same series), but `cleveref` does not do its magic with multiple references.  For instance, if the last `labelboxcode` is changed into `labelboxcode*`, the final line of the output becomes: `one swoop: lis. 1.1 and 1.2 and lis. 1.3`: correct numbers, but 1.3 treated separated from 1.1 and 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

After trial and error, I think I figured it out: adding `label type=labelboxcode` in the `labelboxcode*` definition seems to do the trick.